# sql server 2016 restar meses a un campo decimal (8,0)

Tags: sql, server

En una tabla Tengo un campo `[FECHA2]` pero esta como decimal (8,0) null, como puedo hacer para que reste 6 meses a todos los datos de ese campo sobre el dato del mes actual

```
select  fecha2, CONVERT(datetime, [fecha2]) 
        from [dbo].[tabla] 
        where [fecha2] = DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

sale error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible opción sería convertir primero a varchar(8)

```
Declare @table table (Fecha2 decimal(8,0))
Insert into @table (Fecha2)
values
(20210101),
(20210201),
(20210301),
(20210401),
(20210501),
(20210601),
(20210701),
(20210801),
(20210901),
(20211001),
(20211101),
(20211201);

Select CAST(CAST(t.Fecha2 as varchar(8)) as datetime)

from @table t;
```

[image: Resultado]

Siempre y cuando los datos en origen estén en formato `yyyyMMdd`, entonces ya puedes utilizar la función dateadd al resultado obtenido.

```
Declare @table table (Fecha2 decimal(8,0))
Insert into @table (Fecha2)
values
(20210101),
(20210201),
(20210301),
(20210401),
(20210501),
(20210601),
(20210701),
(20210801),
(20210901),
(20211001),
(20211101),
(20211201);

Select DateAdd(month,-6,(CAST(CAST(t.Fecha2 as varchar(8)) as datetime)))

from @table t
```

[image: Resultado DateAdd]

Comment: Hay que aclarar que para regresar el valor a decimal, también hay que convertir primero a un tipo cadena con el formato 112 de CONVERT. Por eso no se debe trabajar con números para simular fechas (no me importa si Microsoft lo hace)